# Using the same boolean in two different scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a total beginner at Unity and I don't understand how to use a variable in two different scripts.

For example, let's say that I have a script called "player" and another called "logic".

In the player script, I create the boolean "IsAlive", and when I collide with something, I die :

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsAlive = True;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    IsAlive = False;
}
```

Now, I want to do something in the "Logic" script and have to check if the player is alive or not before. How do I do that ? I tried something like :

```
public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public  PlayerScript PlayerScript_logic;
    private bool IsAlive_logic = PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive;
}
```

so that I could use "IsAlive_logic" which would be the same as "IsAlive".

But that is apparently not how if works.
If somebody could help me, please, I'm so lost.

Answer (score 0):

Simply instead of `IsAlive_logic` in all places use `PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive`. Despite the fact that you can't access a non-constant field (`PlayerScript_logic`) when declaring your other fields - it is bad practice to store (and maintain) the same value in multiple places anyway ;)

---

Alternatively if you really for some reason want/need to you could have a property

```
private bool IsAlive_logic => PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive;
// or also
//private bool IsAlive_logic { get => PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive; }
// or also
//private bool IsAlive_logic { get { return PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive; } }
```

which basically simply returns `PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive` everytime you access it. In general this adds some tiny overhead though and it would be better to go through the `PlayerScript_logic.IsAlive` directly...

Comment: Thank you very much! However, when I do that, the game crashes with the error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ", is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Well that would have happened either way .. apparently you forgot to assign `PlayerScript_logic` via the Inspector or using `GetComponent` etc